# php date() method is showing wrong date

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php

$date = 2022;

$str = strtotime(2022); 

echo $str; // 1613161320

echo '<hr/>';

echo date('Y', $str); // 2021
```

why this link `date('Y', $str);` is showing 2021 instead of 2022 ?

Comment: strtotime() doesn't parse 2022 to a year. If you change the last echo to `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` you will get the output `2021-02-12 20:22:00`.

Comment: Kindly read [strtotime manul](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) . It states : Parameters: datetime : A date/time string.   2022 is neither date string nor time string

Comment: @AlivetoDie a four digit input is both a valid date format and time format - they are [listed here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), linked from the manual page in your comment. The issue is that the time format takes priority when valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` expects a formated date string like `10 September 2000` [see php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).
When you want to get a unix timestamp by seperate year, month, day, hour, minute and second values you should have a look at `mktime()` [see php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

So what you want to get the first 2022-date possible is:

```
$str = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2022);
```